# Unknown HZ Value

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, libc

I'm getting a message that prints out of a Linux application (Qt C++) running on an ARM platform:

> Unknown HZ value! (108) Assume 100.

This output shows up periodically in different applications with different values in the parenthesis.

It started happening when I switched from a glibc to eglibc based toolchain to build the applications, kernel and filesystem.

Doesn't seem to be causing any ill-effects, at least not of an immediate nature.

Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: This is a kernel issue, not a (user) programming issue.

Comment: `HZ` (a.k.a. `CLK_TCK`) is an obsolete identifier used to represent the number of clock ticks per second (as used in calls such as `times(2)`).

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.bigismore.com/web-server-security/unknown-hz-value-assume-100-youve-been-hacked/) claims that it means you've been hacked.  Here's one with more detailed [instructions](http://www.tediosity.com/2010/09/23/unknown-hz-value-assume-100/)

Comment: On a commodity desktop that might be the most common reason.  But this is an ARM system. Most exploits have to be specifically targeted.  On such a less common binary architecture - and also one with greater hardware diversity - it would be more logical to first suspect a kernel not properly ported to the hardware on which it is running, or otherwise slightly broken.

Comment: Yes, like Chris said, this is a custom ARM board, clean build. No chance of any hacking going on...

I also suspect something slightly broken about the new kernel/compiler combo being used now...

Comment: Sorry.  Totally missed that it was on ARM.  This probably means that something that you've included is left from old code.  HZ never appears under arch/arm.  Is your eglibc up to date?

Comment: I can confirm that this ment that my Linux CentOS 5 machine was hacked. I followed the instructions above and removed the infected files.

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/434776/hacked-centos-5-server-possible-rootkit-installed

Answer (score 0):

For my Linux CentOS 5 machine this ment that the server was hacked. [See here how it went.](https://serverfault.com/questions/434776/hacked-centos-5-server-possible-rootkit-installed)